# Is it possible to add custom items to System Settings window?

Tags: launcher, system-settings

For example, how to add a "Startup Applications Preferences" launcher to this Window?

[image: System Settings window in 11.10]

Comment: have you tried the dconf-editor for access to the settings

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Add custom App entries to System Settings

[image: Custom Entries in System Settings]
To add a custom app to **System Settings** (**Gnome Control Center**), find its desktop entry file - `/usr/share/applications/{appname}.desktop` and edit it to ensure that the following entries are present:

```
Categories=Settings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;xxxxx;
X-GNOME-Settings-Panel={appname}
```

Replace `{appname}` with the name of the App you're adding to System Settings.
`xxxxx` decides the *Section* where your app is displayed. Replace `xxxxx` with one of these possible options:
**X-GNOME-PersonalSettings**    -   Personal Section
**HardwareSettings**            -   Hardware Section (Note that prefix X-GNOME is not used)
**X-GNOME-SystemSettings**      -   System Section

[image: Edit desktop entries to show in System Settings]

After the modifications run this command:

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

---

This was tried and tested on **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**[12.04](/questions/tagged/12.04) with *gnome-control-center* version 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.12

**Things to Note**:

1. System Settings don't recognise desktop files in
   `~/.local/share/applications` and as a result,it's not possible to
   add Apps to System Settings for one user alone.
2. As noted by [Manish Sinha](https://askubuntu.com/users/52/manish-sinha) in [this Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108060/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-items-to-system-settings-window/119120#119120), Ubuntu uses a
   `gnome-control-center` with Ubuntu specific patches which enables the
   addition of custom entries. As a result,this method is Ubuntu specific and won't     work on vanilla `gnome-control-center` used by other distros.

Comment: Actually, having `X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;X-GNOME-SystemSettings;` in `Categories` and adding `X-GNOME-Settings-Panel=sample` is sufficient.

Comment: @nem75 that didn't work for me on Ubuntu 12.04, but the settings from lancer did

Comment: the settings from lancer allowed me to add gnome-tweak-tool to my System Settings by modifying /usr/share/applications/gnome-tweak-tool.desktop

Comment: If you want the launcher show up under Personal section, use X-GNOME-PersonalSettings instead of X-GNOME-SystemSettings. For Hardware section, use HardwareSettings (note that prefix X-GNOME is not used and doesn't even work. Some inconsistency here, don't you think?)

Comment: Are there any other possible categories besides Personal or System Settings? And what theme are you using?

Answer (score 4):

### 11.10

Right now adding custom items to System Settings is not support upstream from GNOME

Ubuntu patches System Settings `gnome-control-center` so that it can include it's own ubuntu specific entries in it.

Long story short, you need to install `libgnome-control-center-dev` and create a wrapper around your application which is built against gnome-control-center package using `libgnome-control-center-dev` for `pkg-config`

Right now there is no GUI method to add it. You need to do it programmatically using C and it would work only on Ubuntu.

The reasoning for not allowing third party entries (called panels) is [detailed by David Zeuthen](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2011-May/msg00177.html)

```
> Thu, May 12, 2011 at 4:39 PM, Sergey Udaltsov wrote:
> My whole point was that in the ideal world GNOME could be extensible
> enough so that no _forking_ would be necessary. Extension modules, not
> patches. That would be not a side effect of the license but the
> fundamental feature of the architecture. Do you see the difference?

Yes. I also think we tried that with GNOME 2 and failed. I mean, look
at GNOME 2's control center - on all distros, it's a royal mess of
random crap from either GNOME, the distro or 3rd party app written by
a kid in a basement. With GNOME 3.2, we will have a simpler control
center (since the extension mechanism is going away) but it will be
_awesome_.
```

Answer (score 3):

Update of answer from @lancer for Ubuntu 14.04 lts:

It may come from the fork of gnome-system-settings from the ubuntu team as I could read on some blog post somewhere ( can't recall where .. :/ )

anyway, the following 2 lines shows the differences, & a more thorough example follows

```
X-Unity-Settings-Panel={appname}
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;X-Unity-Settings-Panel;xxxx;
```

ex:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=TefApp
Name[C]=TefApp
Exec=/home/stephaneag/Documents/ubuntu_CustomSystemSettingsEntryApp/dummyScript.sh
Comment[C]=dumb dummy app
StartupNotify=true
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=false
# the following is necessary for the .desktop to be accepted in System Settings
# for our stuff to appear in "System" section:
#Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;X-Unity-Settings-Panel;X-GNOME-SystemSettings;
# for our stuff to appear in "Hardware" section:
#Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;X-Unity-Settings-Panel;HardwareSettings;
# for our stuff to appear in the "Personal" section:
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;X-Unity-Settings-Panel;X-GNOME-PersonalSettings;
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Answer (score 1):

Update for 14.04 with specific details on replacing default Users program with users-admin so groups can be changed.

1. install gnome system tools with users-admin

   ```
    sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
   ```
2. Edit users-admin desktop so it shows up in Unity Control Center - see entry below
3. Move old user desktop so it does not show up in Unity Control Center

   ```
   cd /usr/share/applications/
   mv unity-user-accounts-panel.desktop unity-user-accounts-panel.desktop.ORIG
   ```
4. Update database

   ```
   sudo update-desktop-database
   ```

This was tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  Do not know how an system update will effect the updated files.  Will have to inspect on next upgrade.

/usr/share/applications/users.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Users and Groups
Comment=Add or remove users and groups
Exec=users-admin
Icon=config-users
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;X-Unity-Settings-Panel;X-GNOME-SystemSettings;
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-Unity-Settings-Panel=users
```