# Can't see Backup Settings (deja-dup) on System settings

Tags: 15.10, backup, deja-dup

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 and I want to change deja-dup default settings (location and schedule), but I don't see the option on system settings:

[System settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjJFm.png)

I removed and re-installed deja-dup and it's working, because I can run it from the terminal, but `deja-dup --backup` starts immediatily the backup and I can't access the settings.

As far as I can see in `man deja-dup` there is also no option to do this on terminal.

I remember I saw the backup icon in system settings in 14.04, but now it's gone (neither appears when I search "Backup" on the Dash), do you know what's wrong?

Comment: In system settings, is ther not the icon of a safe labelled 'Backups'?. If there is, then that is the one for you to click in order to see Folders, location etc. Oh, I see from the posted image, that there isn't. Please ignore this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deja-dup preferences should be available from the command line by running:

```
deja-dup-preferences
```

Also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108060/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-items-to-system-settings-window) goes into how to add an item to the system settings. You can use

```
 locate "deja-dup-preferences.desktop"
```

to see if you have a .desktop file lying around to modify for this.

Or you could just put the following into a new file at "/usr/share/applications/deja-dup-preferences.desktop"

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=deja-dup

Name=Backups
Comment=Change your backup settings

Icon=deja-dup
TryExec=deja-dup-preferences
Exec=deja-dup-preferences

StartupNotify=true

Type=Application
Categories=Settings;Utility;Archiving;GNOME;GTK;X-GNOME-SystemSettings;

NotShowIn=Unity;

# Translators: Add whatever keywords you want in your language, separated by semicolons
# These keywords are used when searching for applications in dashes, etc.
Keywords=déjà;deja;dup;

X-AppInstall-Ignore=true

Actions=BackUpNow;

[Desktop Action BackUpNow]
Name=Back Up
Exec=deja-dup --backup
```

That should give you back the system settings icon after a new login I think.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I didn't know it `deja-dup-preferences`.  So far I can't get the option appears in system-settings, but with this command it's enought