# How to put Solaar in the System Settings panel?

Tags: unity, system-settings

How do I make a program (in this case, Solaar) appear in the System Settings panel in Ubuntu 16.04?

The package I want to add is located at `/usr/bin/solaar`. I tried taking a look at `/usr/share/applications/solaar.desktop` based on [this question(--PLEASE READ)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108060/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-items-to-system-settings-window), **but nothing in the `Categories` entry looks exactly like what they have in the example, otherwise I would have already changed it (and have tried)**. Here's the whole file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Solaar
Comment=Logitech Unifying Receiver peripherals manager
Exec=solaar
Icon=solaar
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Keywords=logitech;unifying;receiver;mouse;keyboard;
Categories=Utility;GTK;
# This line is provided by the manufacturer, but doesn't produce
# the desired effect when uncommented:
#Categories=Utility;GTK;Settings;HardwareSettings;
# I created this line based on the linked post, but it doesn't work:
#Categories=Utility;GTK;Settings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;HardwareSettings;
#X-GNOME-Settings-Panel=Solaar
```

...when I modified the file, I was sure to `sudo update-desktop-database` as indicated in the linked question.

**Bonus:** I'd like the item to appear under "Hardware."

Comment: Related: [How do I install and configure the latest version of `solaar` to manage my Logitech wireless mouse or keyboard on Linux Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1390784/327339).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make it look like this...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Solaar
Comment=Logitech Unifying Receiver peripherals manager
Exec=solaar
Icon=solaar
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Keywords=logitech;unifying;receiver;mouse;keyboard;
#Categories=Utility;GTK;
Categories=Utility;GTK;Settings;X-Unity-Settings-Panel;HardwareSettings;
X-Unity-Settings-Panel=Solaar
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I did. I just tried again, copy-pasting these values in, in case mine had a typo. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work the way the linked question indicates.

Comment: And you commented out both existing Categories statements, and uncommented the last two lines that you added? Your code doesn't show that.

Comment: True, I am trying to show my file pre-edits (with the things I've tried commented out) but I think I may have found the answer in the linked question. Check this out: http://askubuntu.com/a/647746/253482 -- I'll try it and if it works we can update your answer.

Comment: Okay I suggested an edit! It worked!

Comment: Bravo! Live and learn!

Comment: ...and eat when your blood sugar's low. Thank you for helping me figure this out.

Comment: Question... so now, when you click on Solaar in the System Settings, what do you get if: 1) Solaar is not running, and 2) Solaar is already running?

Comment: If it's already running, I get the Solaar control panel. If I `killall Solaar`, the battery indicator disappears, and when I click on it from System Settings, the first time it appears to do nothing (but the battery indicator reappears), and the second click brings up the Solaar control panel.

Comment: This solution didn't work on Ubuntu 20.10, with Gnome. I don't have `solaar` entry in `gnome-control-center`.

Comment: @harobed This answer applies to 16.04. In 20.10, Solaar now appears in the system tray, and in the list of Applications.