# Adding Custom Item to System Settings? (gnome-control-center)

Tags: gnome, settings, gnome-control-center

How i can adding custom items to gnome-control-center ?
I want adding a item and click to execute something. ("pkexec myapp --settings")

I tryed this but not working : [Is it possible to add custom items to System Settings window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108060/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-items-to-system-settings-window) (Its old answer for outdated gnome-control-center)

[image]